# Why this pie chart legend d3.js does not work?

Tags: d3.js

I made a pie chart and it's works well:

```
var width = 960,
height = 500,
radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var percentageFormat = d3.format("%");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.outerRadius(radius - 10)
.innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.sort(null)
.value(function(d) {
    return d.values;
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


d3.json("staff.json", function(error, json_data) {

var data = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) {
  return d.sex;
})
.rollup(function(d) {
  return d.length;
}).entries(json_data);

data.forEach(function(d) {
d.percentage = d.values / json_data.length;
});

console.log("data variable", data);
console.log("pie(data)", pie(data));

var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
.data(pie(data))
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "arc")
.on('mouseover', function() {
  var current = this;  
  var others = svg.selectAll(".arc").filter(function(el) {
    return this != current
  });
  others.selectAll("path").style('opacity', 0.8);
})
.on('mouseout', function() {
  var current = this;
  d3.select(this)
    .style('opacity', 1);
  var others = svg.selectAll(".arc").filter(function(el) {
    return this != current
  });
  others.selectAll("path").style('opacity', 1);
});


g.append("path")
.attr("d", arc)
.style("fill", function(d, i) {
  return color(i);
});

g.append("text")
.attr("transform", function(d) {
  return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
})
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function(d) {
  console.log("d is", d);
  return percentageFormat(d.data.percentage);
});
});
```

This is file staff.json:
    [{
    "Position" : "Programmer",
        "Name" : "Giacomo Gulizzoni",
         "Age" : 37,
         "Sex" : "Male",
     "Project" : "SmartFactory"
}, {
    "Position" : "Tester",
        "Name" : "Marko Botton",
         "Age" : 34,
         "Sex" : "Male",
     "Project" : "SmartFactory"
}, {
    "Position" : "Tester",
        "Name" : "Mariah Maclachian",
         "Age" : 37,
         "Sex" : "Female",
     "Project" : "SmartFactory"
}, {
    "Position" : "Tester",
        "Name" : "Valerie Liberty",
         "Age" : 25,
         "Sex" : "Female",
     "Project" : "SmartProject"
}, {
    "Position" : "Programmer",
       "Name " : "Guido Jack Gulizzoni",
         "Age" : 22,
         "Sex" : "Male",

I wanted to add legends and following a tutorial I added some code for that. After that it doesn't work any more.

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: This is a tutorial: http://zeroviscosity.com/d3-js-step-by-step/step-3-adding-a-legend And this is my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/aqWPFnDysK8vhBlWqzzs?p=preview

Comment: Could you add some code to your question? Without that it is impossible to pinpoint what the problem could be.

Comment: Made phrases somewhat clearer. Still the author needs to add code and explain in what way "it doesn't work any more".

Comment: What are you trying to plot?  It seems that you are trying to determine a percent based on a non-existent "Position" property...  Did you mean that to be sex?  Age?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I tried to add legends to this pie chart http://plnkr.co/edit/vDsfrCjdlzjRy4qiqBGs?p=preview